# in C++, SFML, How do I draw an animation from another class within a different class?

Tags: c++, animation, visual-studio-2015, sfml

I am making a street fighter type game for my University project using c++ and SFML, I am new to this so I don't really know what I'm doing.
I wanted to have a teleport button that lets the player teleport 700 pixels away from their current position and have an animation (smoke effect) play when they move.
I have made a separate class for this animation which has an update function that plays each frame. But I don't know how to use the animation from the "Teleport" class in the "Player" class.
Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Code:   (the 'isSliding' is a confusing variable name but it's meant to mean teleporting)

```
if ((input->isKeyDown(sf::Keyboard::D)) && (!isSliding) && (hDir != 0))     //slide: if slide is pressed AND cooldown is finished.
{
    cout << "\nSlide pressed!";
    cout << "\nElapsed slide time: " + to_string(slideElapsedTime);
    if (playerStamina >= slideCost)
    {
        //isAttacking = true;
        isSliding = true;
        slideElapsedTime = 0;
        input->setKeyUp(sf::Keyboard::D);
        if (walk.getFlipped())              //if walk is flipped then flip the slide animation.
        {
            duck.setFlipped(true);
        }
        else duck.setFlipped(false);

        currentAnimation = &duck;       //using duck animation for teleport animation.
        currentAnimation->animate(dt);
        currentAnimation->reset();
        setTextureRect(currentAnimation->getCurrentFrame());


        if (isSliding)
        {
            target = sf::Vector2f(getPosition().x + 700 * hDir, getPosition().y);       //set target location (current location + offset)
            direction = target - getPosition();                                     //set direction to travel in (depends on current position)  
            if (getPosition() != target)                                            //if not at same location...
            {
                move(direction*dt*scale);                                           //...then move to target location.
            }

        }
        playerStamina -= slideCost;         //reduce the stamina
        damage = 2;                         //set damage to be dealt to enemy.

                                            //check collision and apply damage

    }

}
```

Comment: How about, when the teleport is activate, you create an animation at the current position and then move the character 700 pixels. You don't need to have anything collaborating.

Comment: @Clearer this is going to sound dumb, but how do I do that?

Comment: when you detect that the power is activate, create a new animation, set its position to the player's current position. add the animation to your list of active animations, adjust the player's position.

Comment: Something like this: `void teleport_player(player& p, std::vector<animation>& animations)
{
 animations.emplace_back(stock_animations["smoke"], p.x, p.y);
 p.x += 700;
}`
Adjust to fit your needs.

Comment: @clearer I have tried adding this code: <pre> if (isSliding)
   {
    teleportAnimation.setPosition(getPosition().x, getPosition().y);
    teleportAnimation.update(dt);


    target = sf::Vector2f(getPosition().x + 700 * hDir, getPosition().y); <code> But this doesn't render the animation though?

Comment: Why do folk these days write such violent projects? In my days it was rendering electron probability distributions around nuclei. Why not build a dating site instead and spread the love?

Comment: I don't have full insight in your code, so I can't really tell you why you're not getting the animation.

Comment: @clearer is there a way I can send you my project (if you have time)?

Comment: @clearer and for anyone trying to see the game, here is the full solution: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nwGNpUxDJbJ8wukw2F0bPwZMZMLszXOg

Comment: Sorry, but I'm at work at the moment -- I doubt I'll have time to help you much more than I already have.

Comment: @Clearer that's okay, thanks for suggestions :)